# Is it a bad idea to change my i18n locale file's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm Taiwanese , I saw most people use 'zh-TW' to represents Taiwan language

but zh-TW contains special character ? so it has strange behavior in rails console.

if I changed my locale to English, it works perfect  `I18n.locale= :en`

But failed to  `I18n.locale= :zh-TW`

```
NameError: uninitialized constant TW
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is it a good idea to change the zh-TW to tw for the Taiwan language ?

1. zh-TW.yml -> tw.yml

In the locale yml file

```
tw:
  hello: "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. `:tw` is not an international Language code. As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module

> The i18n library takes a pragmatic approach to locale keys (after some
>   discussion), including only the locale ("language") part, like :en,
>   :pl, not the region part, like :en-US or :en-GB, which are
>   traditionally used for separating "languages" and "regional setting"
>   or "dialects". Many international applications use only the "language"
>   element of a locale such as :cs, :th or :es (for Czech, Thai and
>   Spanish). However, there are also regional differences within
>   different language groups that may be important. For instance, in the
>   :en-US locale you would have $ as a currency symbol, while in :en-GB,
>   you would have £. Nothing stops you from separating regional and other
>   settings in this way: you just have to provide full "English - United
>   Kingdom" locale in a :en-GB dictionary.

So, you can use `:zh` for Taiwan. No issues.

Comment: Ok, So I change all the `tw` into `zh`, although 'tw' it works perfect now.

Comment: Is that showing Taiwan translations perfectly? How it reacts when you set the default locale to be :tw?